# How to catch all routes in rocket?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I have looked up everywhere but I only found [this](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/issues/261) github issue, but it's from 5 years ago, and rocket has changed a lot.
Is there a way to catch all methods (get, post, head, options, whatever .. .) and all routes (/abc, /abc/xyz, /xyz, /whatever) in rocket.

I tried using the code from the github issue, but rocket api has updated a lot so I can't figure out how.

Comment: The code has certainly changed, but the API in this regard is pretty much the same. You can use `<path..>` to denote a generic path, but there's no way to accept all methods. You need to follow the suggested code in that issue which creates separate routes for each HTTP method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is part of "manual routing" in Rocket, the code linked in the issue you found is now a dead link, but there's a [similar example](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/blob/ae0ccf43f11be5c00bb9cd49996c8bb06a7e1651/examples/manual-routing/src/main.rs) in the current version.
It uses the [`Handler`](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.1/rocket/route/trait.Handler.html) trait with its [impl for functions](https://docs.rs/rocket/0.5.0-rc.1/rocket/route/trait.Handler.html#impl-Handler-1):

```rust
fn hi<'r>(req: &'r Request, _: Data<'r>) -> route::BoxFuture<'r> {
    route::Outcome::from(req, "Hello!").pin()
}

#[rocket::launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    let hello = Route::ranked(2, Get, "/", hi);

    rocket::build()
        .mount("/", vec![hello])
}
```

If you need multiple methods you can loop through them in the same way that's described in the issue and create the routes with

```rust
#[rocket::launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    use rocket::http::Method::*;
    let mut routes = vec![];
    for method in &[Get, Put, Post, Delete, Options, Head, Trace, Connect, Patch] {
        routes.push(Route::new(*method, "/git/<path..>", git_http));
    }
    rocket::build().mount("/", routes)
}
```

The `<path..>` captures all segments (query parameters are caught by default from my testing), and you can get to them using `Request`'s methods.